# How to use loop for following Laravel code?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
    $query1 =  User::where('sponser_id',$_SESSION['ruserid'])->get('userid');
    $count1= count($query1);
    
    $query2 =  User::whereIn('sponser_id',$query1)->get('userid');
    $count2= count($query2);

    $query3 =  User::whereIn('sponser_id',$query2)->get('userid');
    $count3= count($query3);

    $query4 =  User::whereIn('sponser_id',$query3)->get('userid');
    $count4= count($query4);

    $query5 =  User::whereIn('sponser_id',$query4)->get('userid');
    $count5= count($query5);

    $query6 =  User::whereIn('sponser_id',$query5)->get('userid');
    $count6= count($query6);

    $query7 =  User::whereIn('sponser_id',$query6)->get('userid');
    $count7= count($query7);

    $allcount=$count1+$count2+$count3+$count4+$count5+$count6+$count7;
```

> I want to calculate the total downlines of users. This code works fine. But How to simplifies this code using a loop?

Comment: looks like a pyramid schema application ;) what have tried ? read this to improve your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can maybe use `${"query".$i}` in your for loop, it allows you to create variable variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $allcount = 0;

            $query1 = User::where('sponser_id',$_SESSION['ruserid'])->get('userid');
            $count1 = count($query1);

            $allcount = $allcount + $count1;
            for ($i=2; $i<8; $i++) {
                
            if ($i>2){
                $j = $i-1;
                ${"query".$j} = User::whereIn('sponser_id',${"query".($j-1)})->get('userid');
                
            } 
            ${"query".$i} = User::whereIn('sponser_id',${"query".($i-1)})->get('userid');
            ${"count".$i} = count(${"query".$i});

            $allcount = $allcount + ${"count".$i};
            }

            return $allcount;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).